# Pasar datos de un componente a otro

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

Tengo en mi proyecto, la posibilidad de crear dos tipos de cuentas, por lo que el formulario de registro usa un componente de datos comunes(datos necesarios para crear el usuario sin importar el tipo de cuenta) y otro componente con los datos especificos de cada tipo de cuenta, como hago, para desde el componente de datos comunes enviar esos datos al otro componente y asi poder hacer un http.post para registrar el usuario?

Answer (score 0):

Crea un Servicio Compartido.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedDataService {
  datosComunes: any; // Aquí almacenarás los datos comunes

  constructor() { }
}
```

Componente de Datos Comunes

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedDataService } from '../shared-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datos-comunes',
  templateUrl: './datos-comunes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datos-comunes.component.css']
})
export class DatosComunesComponent {
  constructor(private sharedDataService: SharedDataService) { }

  guardarDatos(datos: any) {
    this.sharedDataService.datosComunes = datos;
  }
}
```

Componente de Datos Específicos

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedDataService } from '../shared-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datos-especificos',
  template: `
<form (ngSubmit)="guardarDatos(datosComunes)">
  <!-- Campos de datos comunes -->
</form>
<button (click)="registrarUsuario()">Registrar Usuario</button>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./datos-especificos.component.css']
})
export class DatosEspecificosComponent {
  constructor(private sharedDataService: SharedDataService) { }

  registrarUsuario() {
    const datosComunes = this.sharedDataService.datosComunes;
  }
}
```